# I am struggling to make it so that an int decided by the user is available in different activities

Tags: android, int, visible

I am creating an app to test the user on their knowledge on certain subjects. For each test they will get a score. There score is an int, (finalscore) but I am struggling to make it so that finalscore is visible in other activities. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a singleton extending your `Application`.

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {
  private int finalscore = 0;

  int getPoints() { return finalscore; }
  void setPoints(final int newpoints) { finalscore = newpoints; }

  ...
}
```

So if you have to get or set values for that `int`, just use:

```
GlobalVars globvars = ((GlobalVars) getApplicationContext());
globvars.setPoints(5);
```

This is "project-wide", so you can call it in any `Activity`.

Comment: Why would you do this vs passing an extra properly!?

Comment: This is simpler in some ways. But there's no need to extend Application--any singleton class with static get and set methods would do.

Comment: Personally I'd use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Those are valid approaches as well, probably the `SharedPreferences` is even easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the integer to the next activity by adding it as an extra :

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
nextActivity.putExtra("finalscore",finalScore);
startActivity(nextActivity);
```

Then in the next activity, get the score by using :

```
int finalScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("finalscore", 0);
```

Notice that the string "finalscore" is the same in the two activities. You can use a constant to be sure not to make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the int between activities

When you open a new activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("MY ACTION");
 intent.putExtra("MY_INT_KEY", intValue);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And in onCreate of the next activity

```
 getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_INT_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make some value visible to all activities from your app, you can also use SharedPreferences. These store key-value pairs.

1. Saving

   ```
   //create prefs object, "myprefs" is just a file name where your values will be stored
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

   //store your integer
   editor.putInt("score", scoreValue);

   //save
   editor.commit();
   ```
2. Reading - can be done in any activity

   ```
   //create prefs object, "myprefs" is just a file name where your values will be stored
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   //read the value for key "score", and assign to the variable
   int score = prefs.getInt("score", 0);  //<------ 0 here is default value in case "score" key doesn't exist, you can replace it with any value
   ```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).